# Why group policy can't prevent Windows Update from installing drivers?

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, windows-update, group-policy

After I have uninstalled the device (remove driver software selected) and edited the entries in group policies to prevent driver installation. Windows Update still installed drivers for that device.

How should I stop Windows Update from installing the device?

Below is the configuration of group policy (Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Device Installation > Device Installation Restrictions):
[image]

[image]

Below is the hardware id and the installed driver.
[image]

Comment: You are rebooting after you set the group policy, right??  Try using `pnputil /enum-devices /ids` to find the Class GUID of the driver.  Have you also tried adding all 4 values?  If you block the class GUID for the display driver, you will want to specifically allow, the display adapter driver you want to use.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks. I have added 4 values, but it still installed the driver. I haven't rebooted as I can recall and the IDs are the same as I added even if I rebooted. I will try adding GUID in “Prevent installation of devices using drivers that match these device setup classes” and see what happens.

Comment: @Ramhound It installed the driver again with GUID set.

Comment: Did you reboot your machine?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I rebooted it after setting group policies and removal of the driver and it still install the drivers.